# wordpress exclude js script from a page type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a script problem with a plugin and I have to deactivate a JS script from a certain page, the script is in functions.php

```
wp_enqueue_script( "helper-js", JS_PATH . 'helper.js', array( 'jquery' ), get_bloginfo('version') , true );
```

And I am trying to exclude it from single-room.php

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to wrap the enqueue in a condition that checks the filename, something like

```
if ( basename( get_page_template() ) !== 'single-room.php') {
    wp_enqueue_script( "helper-js", JS_PATH . 'helper.js', array( 'jquery' ), get_bloginfo('version') , true );
}
```

Comment: Well, you'll need something like this, but there's no suprise if it doesn't work by just copy pasting it in, you have to figure out how to get the filename correctly yourself, and there's no guarantee `get_page_template` will return the correct value in all themes/pages.